# Java: Read from Kafka using spark batch job (not streaming)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to write a spark batch job that wakes up every hour and read from Kafka. For this I'm using **org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils#createRDD**. But it needs an offset range(fromOffset to untilOffset).

Is it possible or not? Am I going to the write direction or not?

whatever I googled till now, I found these methods to get the offsets i.e. **org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster#getEarliestLeaderOffsets** & **org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster#getLatestLeaderOffsets**. But I'm not getting how to use these methods to createRDD(or to get offsetRange).

Comment: Kafka provides window timer, which allows Kafka to read the message queue as per the give interval of time. Why are you trying to read manually using the offset?

Comment: @vijayraj34 Can u please elaborate it more? How can we use it in spark batch mode?